# Custom JWT respone in Spring sercurity

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I use API oauth/token to get JWT token in spring sercurity oauth2. I try to add some additional information in the response by using ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo) of enhance method of TokenEnhancer interface. But these additionalInfo added to JWT too, so It is too big. Is there any way to add additionalInfo to the body of oauth/token request, but not in JWT.

```
@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    final Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();
    WebUser webUser = (WebUser) authentication.getUserAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    additionalInfo.put("user_name", authentication.getName());
    additionalInfo.put("roles", authentication.getAuthorities());
    if(webUser.getFunctions() != null) {
        additionalInfo.put("functions",  webUser.getFunctions().toString());
    }else {
        additionalInfo.put("functions",  null);
    }

    ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
    return accessToken;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you modify a token, it is said to be "enhancing the token" in Spring context. Logically, you should first convert the token into JWT then add the other properties so that they do not contribute to you payload of JWT.

Here is a snippet from my project built using spring boot

```java
 @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(
                Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), jwtAccessTokenConverter()));

        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
                .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter())
                .tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }
```

In here, I'm adding few properties using the `tokenEnhancer()` to my token and then enhancing that token to become a JWT using `jwtAccessTokenEnhancer()`. If I reverse the order here, I get what you are desire.